# How to rewrite url between page and category?

Tags: category, url, url-rewrite, menu, page

I'm a magento beginner.
I have problem. please help me

My problem is I have create one **category(about us)** and one **page(about us)**.
when i click in menu category(about us), it will show the page(about us).
I tried two more times. I spent the full day. help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the url key attribute the same for the category and for the cms page?